# Initialize 2-D array uniformly in numpy

Tags: numpy, reinforcement-learning

I want to create a probability distribution stochastic policy for **reinforcement learning**.

```
e.i policy[s,a] = P(take action a | in state s), where n_states=500 and n_actions=6
```

Since we still use integer state and action representations, I need to use a 2-dimensional array to represent the policy.

How can I initialize my policy **uniformly**? that is, probabilities of all actions should be equal.

Comment: What about doing `np.ones((n_states, n_actions)) * np.random.random()`?

Comment: `policy = np.full(1. / n_actions, (n_states, n_actions))`?

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci and @Jdehesa, thanks guys, you are gentlemen and scholars. Go to my stable and take my finest stallions. They are yours, I call them Wind grazer and GlueStick.

For **beginners** `policy = np.full(fill_value = 1. / n_actions, shape = (n_states, n_actions))`

Answer (score 2):

`policy = np.full(fill_value = 1. / n_actions, shape = (n_states, n_actions))` @Jdehesa